# Including a test for a whitespace in addition to other tests in a perl pattern match

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace

I want to search a given string for accented or weird symbolic characters which occur when exporting/importing between MySQL and Excel when using a tab separated text file.

To do this i have tried `!~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]\s/` - i thought this pattern would test a given string and identify those that contained anything other than `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or a white space?

When putting this into a regex tester on line the `\s` works on its own but when i add the `a-zA-Z0-9` element it cancels out the white space.

The white space could be all that is contained in the string or it could be at the beginning or end, what is the correct regex to capture this please?

Comment: The regex as it stands is correct, and the character class doesn't "_cancel out the white space_".  The problem is likely that it just doesn't match the strings you are trying it with.  Can you show your typical input and explain more clearly what exactly you need to match?

Comment: You regex is for 1 character `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` followed by 1 whitespace. Is that your intention?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex for that. This will only select those words that contain invalid characters.

```
\b\S*(?=[^A-Za-z0-9\s]+\b)\S*\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lboS4L/1)

Or if you just want to capture anything but the a-zA-Z0-9 and white space then you can try this:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]
```

[Demo2](https://regex101.com/r/lboS4L/2/)